# Array of sets in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, set

Is there a way to create an array of sets in Matlab.

Eg: I have:

```
a = ones(10,1);
b = zeros(10,1);
```

I need c such that c = [(1,0); (1,0); ...], i.e. each set in c has first element from a and 2nd element from b with the corresponding index.

Also is there some way I can check if an unknown set (x,y) is in c.

Can you all please help me out? I am a Matlab noob. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are not *sets* in your understanding in MATLAB (I assume that you are thinking of *tuples* on Python...) But there are *cell*s in MATLAB. That is a data type that can store pretty much anything (you may think of *pointer*s if you are familiar with the concept). It is indicated by using `{` `}`.
Knowing this, you could come up with a cell of arrays and check them using `cellfun`

```
% create a cell of numeric arrays
C = {[1,0],[0,2],[99,-1]}
% check which input is equal to the array [1,0]
lg = cellfun(@(x)isequal(x,[1,0]),C)
```

Note that you access the address of a cell with `()` and the content of a cell with `{}`. `[]` always indicate arrays of something. We come to this in a moment.

**OK, this was the part that you asked for; now there is a bonus**:

That you use the term *set* makes me feel that they always have the same size. So why not create an array of arrays (or better an array of vectors, which is a matrix) and check this matrix column-wise?

```
% array of vectors (there is a way with less brackets but this way is clearer):
M = [[1;0],[0;2],[99;-1]]
% check at which column (direction ",1") all rows are equal to the proposed vector:
lg = all(M == [0;2],1)
```

This way is a bit clearer, better in terms of memory and faster. 
Note that both variables `lg` are arrays of logicals. You can use them directly to index the original variable, i.e. `M(:,lg)` and `C{lg}` returns the *set* that you are looking for.

Comment: Good solution, the second one (+1). Just wanted to leave a note: equality only works consistently for integer values, and should be used carefully with floating-point values.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to get logical value regarding if `p` is in `C`, maybe you can try the code below

```
any(sum((C-p).^2,2)==0)
```

or

```
any(all(C-p==0,2))
```

**Example**

```
C = [1,2;
     3,-1;
     1,1;
     -2,5];

p1 = [1,2];
p2 = [1,-2];

>> any(sum((C-p1).^2,2)==0) # indicating p1 is in C
ans = 1
>> any(sum((C-p2).^2,2)==0) # indicating p2 is not in C
ans = 0
>> any(all(C-p1==0,2))
ans = 1
>> any(all(C-p2==0,2))
ans = 0
```

Comment: You could also use `any(all(C-p1==0,2))`

Comment: @Daniel thanks for advice, and it's added to the answer